# VirtualService routing only uses one host

Tags: networking, kubernetes, istio

I have the following VirtualService:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: external-vs
  namespace: dev
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - http-gateway
  http:
    - name: "postauth"
      match:
      - uri:
        exact: /postauth
      route:
        - destination:
            port:
              number: 8080
            host: postauth
    - name: "frontend"
      match:
        - uri:
          exact: /app
      route:
        - destination:
            port:
              number: 8081
            host: sa-frontend
```

I would expect that calls to the /postauth endpoint would be routed to the postauth service and calls to the /app endpoint would be routed to the sa-frontend service. What is happening is that all calls end up being routed to the first router in the file, in the above case to postauth, but if I change the order it will be to sa-frontend

All services and deployments are in the same namespace (dev).

Is that somehow the expected behaviour? My interpretation is that the above should only allow calls to the /postauth and /app endpoints and nothing else, and route these to their respective services.

Comment: It's not expected behavior, as stated it should work respectively to the first and the second service. Did you get any errors related to this issue?

Comment: After virtualservice creation what is the output for istio routes?
`istioctl pc routes $(kubectl get pods -l istio=ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}' -n istio-system).istio-system -o json`
Please remove also names from this yaml and try again. In the provided above output you should notice routes for both entries.

Comment: In addition what is your istio version?

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentaion for Istio 1.3](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/virtual-service/) in HTTPMatchRequest you can find

> Field: *name*, Type: *string*

I have compared those settings between 1.1 and 1.3 versions:
In version 1.3.4 this paramereter is working properly and the routes were propagated with the names:

```
[
    {
        "name": "http.80",
        "virtualHosts": [
            {
                "name": "*:80",
                "domains": [
                    "*",
                    "*:80"
                ],
                "routes": [
                    {
                        "name": "ala1",
                        "match": {
                            "prefix": "/hello1",
                            "caseSensitive": true
                        },
                        "route": {
                            "cluster": "outbound|9020||hello1.default.svc.cluster.local",
.
.
.

                    {
                        "name": "ala2",
                        "match": {
                            "prefix": "/hello2",
                            "caseSensitive": true
                        },
                        "route": {
                            "cluster": "outbound|9030||hello2.default.svc.cluster.local",
```

While in version 1.1 it's not working properly. In those cases please verify your settings with appropriate [release](https://archive.istio.io/).

In addition please refer to [Troubleshooting](https://istio.io/docs/ops/troubleshooting/proxy-cmd/) section.

You can verify your applied configuration (changes) inside the cluster, f.e.:
How Envoy instance was configured:

```
istioctl proxy-config cluster -n istio-system your_istio-ingressgateway-name
```

Verify routes configuration and virtual hosts for services:

```
istioctl proxy-config routes -n istio-system your_istio-ingressgateway-name -o json
```

Hope this help.